# How long is a CA Statement valid as per UKIV for UK visit visa purposes?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-of-funds, proof-provenance-of-funds

I got my CA (Chartered Accountant) Statement done a month back. Which include the property Assessment, other Immovable assets (to prove financial ties to back home), family income and available liquid funds. However this is 40 days old. I am planning to apply for Visa now . Can I use this old CA Statement or should i get a new one again. Everything remains same, just the available liquid funds and bank statements have changed since the CA statement.

Comment: What does CA stand for? Who prepared it?  Most importantly, have your circumstances changed since the report was prepared?

Comment: CA is Chartered Accountant . Available balance and Bank statements have changed. other stuff like immovable assets monthly income all remains same.

Comment: They don't care about chartered accountant statements. It's doubtful anyone will look at it.

Comment: Thanks @GayotFow. The only reasons I wanted these to be included is that they contain details about immovable Assets. Now the available balance as per bank statements is say ex £4k but as per the CA report the available balance  is £3k as on certain date  .So what's the final available balance Visa Officer will consider to make a decision ?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Answer (score 1):

In the link kindly provided by @Gayot Fow is mention of:

> eg bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months

What you are asking about is neither a bank statement nor a payslip but the above does give some indication of how up-to-date the ECO expects financial records to be, with 40 days being well within a reasonable time frame.

The [Guide to supporting documents: visiting the UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) specifically discounts some financial information, unless specifically requested, more than a year old:

> bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of 
>   application

Bank statements and payslips are somewhat special cases where provision of a series at monthly intervals may be appropriate better to show a general pattern than just a snapshot that might not be representative. For example, a bank statement more than 6 months old may be the most practical way to demonstrate participation in a bonus scheme that only pays out twice a year.

If your Chartered Accountant's statement is important for your application (and note @Gayot's Comment *They don't care about chartered accountant statements. It's doubtful anyone will look at it.*) then I'd suggest anything up to 180 days is as good as anything more recent. After that, maybe request a new statement.